# Add multiple child form

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a form like this .
[image]

I want to add button (+) before Action N° : ,
each time I click on (+) it shows me a child-form if I have a second action to add. this child-form must contain only this fields.it's like I want this button to allow me to add several actions for this form, but the other fields must have a fixed value.
[image]
When I create this form I need to have data like this in my database .
[image]

I m using spring boot in back end and postgres as database.

Any suggestion how we can do this ?

Comment: using ReactiveForms, the FormArray is dedicated to a such use case.

Comment: is it going to work with sql database ?

Comment: on Angular side, create an array of items before making your http request, each item including the first part of your form and one of the child form. So it'll match your sql model.

Comment: I didn't use formbuilder for other formcontainer , can I use formbuilder.arrayform for just action part ??

Answer (score 0):

```
    matrimonyForm: FormGroup;
    
    constructor(public formBuilder: FormBuilder){
       this.matrimonyForm = this.formBuilder.group({contact_person: new FormArray([])});
    }    
    get c() { return this.matrimonyForm.controls['contact_person'] as FormArray; }
            
    Click on Add button call addMore()
    
    addMore(){
          this.c.push(this.formBuilder.group({ name: ['', Validators.required], contact_no: ['', Validators.required], relation: ['', Validators.required] }));
        }

now you can get dynamic *contact_person*
```